# Remove IMG tag from HTML using Regex - Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have HTML and I want to remove IMG tag from it.

I am not good at regex, I have this function but it does not remove IMG tag

```
def remove_img_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<img.*?/>')
    return p.sub('', data)
```

What is the proper regex? I don't want to use any library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to capture `img` tag and replace it with empty string.

```
clean_data = re.sub("(<img.*?>)", "", data, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

You'll be passing HTML content in `data`. Regex will remove all `img` tags, their content and return clean data in `clean_data` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
image_tag = re.compile(r'<img.*?/>').search(data).group()
data.replace(image_tag, '')
```